# How to calculate how much bandwidth a video used with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to calculate how much bandwidth a user is consuming in a video with javascript, for example, the user will not see the entire video so I want to calculate how bandwidth for the viewing time but I have no idea how to start this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const bandwidth = estimateBandwidth();`

`const quality = fromBandwidthToQuality(bandwidth);`

Comment: It's built-in javascript API

Comment: you can refer http-stream plugin for this. https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming

Comment: How do you serve this video? Are you in control of the server-side?

Comment: Yes I have control of the server and  i know the file size i am serving l guess this can be done by time watched @Kaiido

Comment: Nope, time watch won't give you much. The most important is "how do you serve this video?". From a simple `<video src="myfile.mp4">`? Then you'd need server side to let you know about it. By MSE? Then you can check how much data you did `fetch`.

Comment: the video will be a direct URL from AWS s3

Comment: I have an idea How about like this, time watched since I know what the file size I can compare and find the bandwidth right ? or am I wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the first thing that comes in my mind is to approximate the traffic (it depends by sampling rate of the video, that can be dynamic and not fixed).

**Approximate network traffic**

```
function loaded()
{
    var size = 4096; // video size
    var v = document.getElementById('videoID');
    var r = v.buffered;
    var total = v.duration;

    var start = r.start(0);
    var end = r.end(0);
    var percentDownloaded = (end/total)*100;
    var percentOfSize = (size/100)*percentDownloaded;

    console.log(percentOfSize);
}   

$('#videoID').bind('progress', function() 
{
    loaded();
}
);
```

**Tracking real network traffic**
If you want to retrieve consistent data some browsers implements *Resource Timing API*.
You can find more info about that API [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-resource-timing-1-20170330/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API)